# Цвет графика функции в windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Имеется две проблемы, прошу подсказать что не так:

1) Нужно нарисовать два графика функций. Функции то отрисовываются, но одинаковыми цветами, хотя задавал цвета и в пункте 'Series' в параметрах чарта и отдельными методами.

2) При нажатии на кнопку solveButton рисуется сначала первая функция и лишь после повторного нажатия вторая.

Код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(nBox.Text); // кол-во точек(иксов)

        double[] xs = new double[n]; //иксы
        double[] fxs = new double[n]; //значение функции в иксе
        double[] result = new double[n]; // значение интерполированной функции

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            xs[i] = (Math.PI / n) * (i + 1);
            fxs[i] = Function(xs[i]);
            result[i] = NDDP(xs[i], n, xs, fxs);
            chart1.Series["default"].Points.AddXY(xs[i], Function(xs[i]));
            chart1.Series["interpolated"].Points.AddXY(xs[i], result[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это не faq. И вообще, 3 тега из 5 лишние.

Comment: Нашел ошибку, тема закрыта.